# nodejs could not console log data from mongodb atlas

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

nodejs connects to atlas succesfully but when i try to console log the data I get error

```
const uri = "mongodb+srv://daww:pass@cluster0-shard-00-00-fmmcx.mongodb.net/admin"

MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, client) {
   if(err) {
        console.log('Error occurred while connecting to MongoDB Atlas...\n',err);
   }
   console.log('Connected...');
   const collection = client.db("star").collection("clc").find({}).toArray(function(err,result){

    if(err) throw err;

    console.log(result)

   });

   client.close();
});
```

I was expecting a json object with all the content of the database however, I am getting the following error

```
MongoNetworkError: connection destroyed, not possible to instantiate cursor
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using an asynchronous method `find` to retrieve data. The data will only get logged when the method finishes executing and the callback function gets executed. Meanwhile, the last `client.close()` statement will close the connection before your data gets retrieved.

Try commenting out the close statement or moving it inside your method callback.

Answer (score 0):

Check your **IP Address** is **white listed** under **MongoDB Atlas  Cluster>Security tab**